# Setting block as link using anchor tag in another block

Tags: magento2.3.x

In my theme I have created block of contact-us,about-us,footer and I want to set contact-us block as link using anchor tag in footer block.  I don't know how to set this using admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to create Pages to fullfill the requirement

Create different pages from admin for **Contact-us** and **About-us**

Then in footer block add link of the pages.

Comment: it is not possible using blocks to create links.